# Sendgrid integration with SAPUI5 app returns '400 Bad Request' on POST but works on Postman

Tags: javascript, rest, cordova, sapui5, sendgrid

I'm developing a cordova hybrid app that utilizes UI5 library. I need to be able to send as Email from the app so I decided to use Sendgrid API and, since I had issues with the NodeJS module, I'm creating an AJAX request. I've previously tested the request with Postman, being able to successfully send emails. But, as I tried to do the same request from the app, I've stumbled upon a status '400 Bad Request' without further information. Here goes the code snippet:

```
            var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
                "method": "POST",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer [REDACTED]",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache"
                },
                "processData": false,
                "data": {
                    "personalizations": [
                        {
                        "to": [
                            {
                                "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
                            }
                        ],
                        "subject": "Contato do app"
                        }
                    ],
                    "from": {
                        "email": "anotheremail@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "text/plain",
                            "value":  formatEmail //variable with the email text
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }

            $.ajax(settings).then(
                function success(response, status) {
                    dialog.close();
                    if (status == 202){
                        MessageBox.confirm('Mensagem enviada com sucesso', {
                            actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK],
                            onClose: function(sAction){
                                that.onNavBack()
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        MessageBox.error('Erro!');
                    }
                },

                function fail(data, status){
                    dialog.close();
                    MessageBox.error('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + status + ' DEBUGDATA: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                }  
            );
```

I really can't figure out the reason as to why this happens because the snippet generated by Postman is very similar to my code. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

usually HTTP 400 means bad request and it means that you're passing the wrong parameters to the HTTP POST request.